# Discord.js - Attempting to add a delay to Deleting message command

Tags: javascript, discord

New to coding here;
I'm making a discord bot.
I want to add a timer function to this "clear messages" command in order to wait a couple seconds before it proceeds to actually clear the messages, and let the user know what is about to be deleted.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "Clears messages",
    async execute (message, args){
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply(`You can't use this command.`);
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Enter the amount of messages that you would like to clear.");
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Enter a number.");

        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("100 messages is the highest amount of messages you can clear.");
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("1 messages is the least amount of messages you can clear.");
        
        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 2 + args[0]}).then(messages =>{
            message.channel.send('Deleting '+args[0]+' messages in 5 seconds...')
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        });
    }
}
```

When fetching the messages, I want it to also grab the two new messages made by the one typing the command, and the bots response.
I tried adding a timer function here:

```
await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 2 + args[0]}).then(messages =>{
            message.channel.send('Deleting '+args[0]+' messages in 5 seconds...')
            setTimeout(5000)
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
```

but it results in the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received 5000
    at setTimeout (timers.js:135:3)
    at C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\lucariobot\commands\clear.js:14:13
```

Putting the setTimeout (as well as the warning message) above the *await message.channel.messages.fetch* function doesn't fix my problem either.
Not sure how I would implement it if its going to mess with fetching the messages I want deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout`'s first argument is the callback which will be invoked after the duration (the second argument)

For example,

```js
await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 2 + args[0]}).then(messages =>{
    message.channel.send('Deleting '+args[0]+' messages in 5 seconds...')
    setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
    }, 5000)
    ...
```

As a general note, mixing `await` and classic Promise chaining (`.then`) is interesting. Something like

```js
// helper so you can await a setTimeout
function sleep(seconds) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, seconds * 1000))
}


const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 2 + args[0]})
message.channel.send('Deleting '+args[0]+' messages in 5 seconds...')
await sleep(5) // see above
message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
```

keeps your code flat and, imo more readable.